# How do I find closest value to an input number in pandas column / series?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe which looks like this

```
pd.DataFrame({'A': ['C1', 'C1', 'C1', 'C1', 'C2', 'C2', 'C2', 'C2'],
  ...:                    'B': [1, 3, 6, 9, 2, 3, 4, 8]})
Out[3]: 
    A  B
0  C1  1
1  C1  3
2  C1  6
3  C1  9
4  C2  2
5  C2  3
6  C2  4
7  C2  8
```

for each group in column 'A' i need to find the closest value to 5.

my resulting dataframe should look like this

```
    A  B      C
0  C1  1  False
1  C1  3  False
2  C1  6   True
3  C1  9  False
4  C2  2  False
5  C2  3  False
6  C2  4  True
7  C2  8  False
```

Logic

in group 'C1' 6 is closest to 5
in group 'C2' 4 is closest to 5

how can this be achieved in ideally 1 line of code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's your logic to code, not quite one line though:

```
# distance to 5
s=df['B'].sub(5).abs()

# groupby 'A' and find the min
df['C'] = s == s.groupby(df['A']).transform('min')
```

Output:

```
    A  B      C
0  C1  1  False
1  C1  3  False
2  C1  6   True
3  C1  9  False
4  C2  2  False
5  C2  3  False
6  C2  4   True
7  C2  8  False
```